# Set maxWidth of widget according to width of sibling

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a scrollable list of image/caption columns.
The captions should be at most as wide as the image.

The code I have so far is below:

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: ... // an arbitrary height, needed because I have multiple of these in a column 
  child: ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemBuilder: (context, i) => Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(images[i]), // an image
        Text(captions[i]), // a caption
      ]
    ),
  ),
)
```

It appears to me that I need some way to get the width the image ends up at after layout, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't catch your question but i think that whats your asking for:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myImageAndCaption = [
      ["assets/images/banane.jpg", "caption1"],
      ["assets/images/banane.jpg", "caption2"],
      ["assets/images/banane.jpg", "caption3"],
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: Scaffold(
          body: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: myImageAndCaption.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, itemCount) => Column(
              mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
               Image.asset(
                  myImageAndCaption[itemCount].first,
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.7,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.6,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.3,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.6,
                  child: FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    child: Text(myImageAndCaption[itemCount].last),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

result:  [click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uwUL.jpg)    Hope it helped you.

Comment: This doesn't work, as I need the ScrollView to have a horizontal scroll direction

Comment: sorry didnt saw that you wanted some horizontal scrolling im too lazy to explain what i did here 
you should do some documentation on mediaQuery and other widget  good luck